# Is conjugate transpose the "unique" way to define an involution on $M_n(\mathbb C)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> > Definition: An *involution* on an algebra $A$ is a conjugate-linear map $a \mapsto a^*$, such that $a^{**}=a$, and $(ab)^*=b^*a^*.$

I can't think of any other ways to define the involution on $M_n(\mathbb C)$(all $n\times n$ matrices), so I feel like it should be unique in some sense. Let

$$f:M_n(\mathbb C) \to M_n(\mathbb C)$$

be an involution, then is $f$ necessary a conjugate transpose or having a standard form closely related to a conjugate transpose?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: He specified "conjugate-linear".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, actually the involutions you describe are in bijective correspondance with similarity classes of non-degenerate hermitian forms on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Precisely, let $h:\mathbb{C}^n\times \mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}$ be a non-degenerate hermitian form. Then you have the adjunction relative to $h$ : $h(u(x),y) = h(x,u^*(y))$, and $u\mapsto u^*$ is a semi-linear involution on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Conversely, any involution is of this form, and two hermitian forms define the same involution iff they are similar, ie there is $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $h=\lambda h'$.

How to see this : suppose in general you have two involutions (that is involutive anti-automorphisms) on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, say $\sigma$ and $\tau$. They restrict to involutions on the center $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose $\sigma_{|\mathbb{C}} = \tau_{|\mathbb{C}} = \iota$. Then $\theta = \sigma\circ \tau$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$-algebra of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ (because the actions of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ on the center cancel each other out). But it is ver standard that any automorphism of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is inner : so $\theta(M) = H^{-1}MH$. This means that $\sigma(M) = H^{-1}\tau(M)H$.

Conversely, given $\tau$, if $H\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, you can define $\sigma(M) = H^{-1}\tau(M)H$, which gives you an anti-automorphism of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $\sigma_{|\mathbb{C}} = \iota$. Now it's not hard to see that $\sigma^2 = Id$ iff $\tau(H) = \lambda H$ for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$. It requires a somewhat subtle argument to see that by replacing $H$ with a scalar multiple (which doesn't change $\sigma$) you can always take $\lambda = 1$ (this follows from an easy case of the Hilbert 90 theorem).

The link with hermitian forms is the following : suppose you choose $\tau$ the usual conjugate-transpose, so in particular $\iota$ is the complex conjugation. Then the condition $\tau(H)=H$ says that $H$ is a hermitian matrix. It is the matrix of a hermitian form $h$ in the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$, and $\sigma$ is the adjunction for $h$.

Comment: No, it's quite easy : if you compose any two such involutions, it gives you a $\mathbb{C}$-linear automorphism of the algebra $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, and it is a standard undergrad exercise to show that any such automorphism is inner. So any semi-linear anti-automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ is the composition of the usual conjugate-transpose and the conjugation by some matrix (and it's not hard to see that for the anti-automorphism to be involutive is equivalent to the matrix being hermitian (modulo a scalar constant).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By definition, we require $**=id$. But $M \mapsto H^{-1}M^* H \mapsto H^{-1}H^{-1}M HH=M$?

Comment: Your formula is not the right one : the square of the involution above is $M\mapsto H^{-1}(H^{-1}M^*H)^*H = (H^{-1}H^*)M(H^{*-1}H)$, so it is involutive when $H = H^*$ ie $H$ is hermitian, as announced.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mixed up unitary matrices and Hermitian matrices. But it still take me some time to digest your answer.

Comment: I edited a bit to make it (hopefully) clearer.